# Replace values in power query column using python?

Tags: python, powerbi, powerquery

Newbie in Power BI/Power query and python.  I hope to ask this question succinctly.

I have a "primary" query in PBI but need to change the values of one column (categories) based on the values in the (description) column.  I feel there is a better solution than a new conditional if/else column, or ReplaceReplacer.text in M Code.

An I idea I had was to create a list or query of all values in (description) that need to have their category changed , and somehow use python to iterate through the (description) list and when it finds a value in (description), it knows to drop the new value into category.

I've googled extensively but can't find that kind of "loop" that I can drop a python script into Power Query/Power BI.

What direction should I be heading in, or am I asking the right questions?  I'd appreciate any advice!

John

Comment: Can you share some sample data from both column? then your expected output in the third column?

Comment: Here's a link to a sample file of what i'm trying to do - based on the values in the "Description" column, change the value in new column "NewCategory".  As you can see, current categories are inaccurate, so analysis is quite limited. https://1drv.ms/x/s!AreUw6Bika4qjRwS8SFx0WCTD74w?e=wcwA9E

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are having a rather simple ETL task at hand that clearly doesn't justify incorporating another language like Python/Pandas.

Given the limited information you are sharing I would imagine to use a separate mapping table for your categories and then merge that one with your original table. And eventually you only keep the columns you are interested in.

E.g. this **mapping** or **translation table** has 2 columns: `OLD` and `NEW`. Then you **merge** this mapping table with your data table such that `OLD` equals your `Description` column (the GUI will help you with that) and then expand the newly generated column. Finally rename the columns you want to keep and remove all the rest. This is way more efficient than 100 replacements.

Comment: It's so simple, I don't even know what an ETL is.  I know this is not rocket science - to change the value of one column based on the value in another in power query - I'ne googled the hell out of this.  Best ideas so far I have are long statements such as 100's of if/else's or statements like the following:  #"Replaced Value8"= Table.ReplaceValue(#"Replaced Value7", each [Description], each if Text.Contains([Original Description],"UPWRKESC") then "Upwork" else [Description], Replacer.ReplaceValue,{"Description"}),

Comment: There is no "UPWRKESC" in your Test data? However, this really looks like you need a separate mapping or translation table like I suggested in the answer.

Comment: That UPWRKESC was a bad example - if we can go back to the table pls... - notice row 2.  in [description] value is "paypal transfer".  [category] is "transfer".  for me this is not useful - "payment" is better.  So the effort here is to identify those values in [description] that have improper [category] values, and replace those [category] values with pertinent values that describe the item accurately.  its like if i had List.Accumulate with find a "find values" list from (description)  and "replace values" list for [categories] that need to be changed. Have to be missing some simple solution

Comment: Thanks for all the help Peter.  I may be slowly wrapping my head around this.  This page goes about it I think in a similar way, but its graphical, so I can ,with some study, possibly get it  [link](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Power-Query/Using-a-mapping-table-to-replace-multiple-values-in-multiple/td-p/776898)

Comment: Hi Peter - I may  need a few days to get through this and try yours and the other method.  Will certainly give you the upvote if yours is the wiser choice - my only concern is it will not be an automatic process in the query editor (nor will the other, similar method).  So, this the best Microsoft can do for the professional community do assemble accurate data, yes? yeesh.  Hence the interest in Python.